# Decrypting a BitLockered USB drive

Tags: disk-encryption, bitlocker

I have encrypted a USB drive with BitLocker and I have lost the password and the hash backup. I have tried to search for something to decrypt the drive but came short. I have imaged the USB drive and was wondering is there a way to decrypt an image file?

Comment: If there was an easy way, then BitLocker would not be much of a protection.

Answer (score 2):

As @schroeder mentioned in the comment, the design goal of a product like BitLocker is to prevent exactly what you are asking.

- It is impossible to decrypt an encrypted drive without a key? No - you *can* exhaustively search the entire key space until you locate one that works - if you can tell that is the case.
- Is it feasible to decrypt an encrypted drive without a key within a reasonable amount of time and effort? No, it could take millenia to complete such a task.

[Is there any way to crack a Bitlocker drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26329/is-there-any-way-to-crack-a-bitlocker-drive?rq=1)

Comment: "millenia"? more like billions of years by pooling all of today's computing resources

Comment: for the sake of comparison, centuries or millenia or billions of years are equally unrealistic to wait for.

Comment: Millenia can be reduce to one year given enough computers. Thus decryptable.